# Calculus of residue of function around poles of fractional order (complex analysis)

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

> The complex function $f(z)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{z^2+r_0z}}$ with $r_0>0$ has two poles (at $z=0$ and $z=-r_0$). But they are not simple poles. They are poles of fractional order. Am I right? How I can calculate residue of the function at the poles? Please help me.

Thanks

Vahid

Comment: What if the function is expresed in a form $g(z)=\frac{1}{(z+1)\sqrt{z^2+r_0z}}$ with $r_0>0$ ?
Here the function $g(z)$ has a simple pole of -1 as weel as the square rooted denominator. Is it possible to evaluate the integral of $g(z)$ w.r.t $z$ using residue theorem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is that these are not poles - they are branch point singularities.  They are not covered by the residue theorem, and if you were to include this function in a contour integral, you would want to point your contour so as to not include the branch cut $z \in [-r_0,0]$ inside the contour.